# How to apply multiple regular expression on single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Currently I have a regular expression for zip-codes for the U.S.:

```
validates :zip,
          presence: true, 
          format: { with: /\A\d{5}(-\d{4})?\z/ }
```

I want to use different regular expressions for other countries on the same  zip-code so the regular expression should be used according to the country:

- For Australia 4 digits
- For Canada 6 digits alphanumeric
- For UK 6-7 digits alphanumeric

Can someone suggest how can I full fill my requirement?

Comment: is country another field on this model?

Comment: Yes, Country is another field in this model. and I want to validate zip code on this basis of each country.

Comment: Your question isn't asked well. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You should show us the minimum code necessary that demonstrates what you tried. Without that it looks like you want us to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to write a method to help you:

```
  validates :zip, presence: true, with: :zip_validator

  def zip_validator
    case country
    when 'AU'
      # some regex or fail
    when 'CA'
      # some other regex or fail
    when 'UK'
      # some other regex or fail
    else
      # should this fail?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give a lambda that returns a Regexp as the `:with` option for the format validator ([see `:with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of)), which makes this nice and clean:

```
ZIP_COUNTRY_FORMATS = {
  'US' => /\A\d{5}(-\d{4})?\z/,
  'Australia' => /\A\d{4}\z/,
  # ...
}

validates :zip, presence: true,
  format: { with: ->(record){ ZIP_COUNTRY_FORMATS.fetch(record.country) } }
```

Note that uses `Hash#fetch` instead of `Hash#[]` so that if a `country` that doesn't exist is given it will raise a KeyError just as a sanity check. Alternatively you could return a default Regexp that matches anything:

```
ZIP_COUNTRY_FORMATS.fetch(record.country, //)
```

...or nothing:

```
ZIP_COUNTRY_FORMATS.fetch(record.country, /.\A/)
```

...depending on the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we give examples of valid postal codes for each country in a hash such as the following.

```
example_pcs = {
  US:  ["",   "98230", "98230-1346"],
  CAN: ["*",  "V8V 3A2"],
  OZ:  ["!*", "NSW 1130", "ACT 0255", "VIC 3794", "QLD 4000", "SA 5664",
              "WA 6500", "TAS 7430", "NT 0874"]
}
```

where the first element of each array is a string of codes that will be explained later.

We can construct a regex for each country from this information. (The information would undoubtedly be different in a real application, but I am just presenting the general idea.) For each country we construct a regex for each example postal code, using in part the above-mentioned codes. We then take the union of those regexes to obtain a single regex for that country. Here's one way the regex for an example postal code might be constructed.

```
def make_regex(str, codes='')
  rstr = str.each_char.chunk do |c|
    case c
    when /\d/          then :DIGIT
    when /[[:alpha:]]/ then :ALPHA
    when /\s/          then :WHITE
    else                    :OTHER
    end
  end.
  map do |type, arr|
    case type
    when :ALPHA
      if codes.include?('!')
        arr
      elsif arr.size == 1
        "[[:alpha:]]"
      else "[[:alpha:]]\{#{arr.size}\}"
      end
    when :DIGIT
      (arr.size == 1) ? "\\d" : "\\d\{#{arr.size}\}"
    when :WHITE
      case codes
      when /\*/ then "\\s*"
      when /\+/ then "\\s+"
      else (arr.size == 1) ? "\\s" : "\\s\{#{arr.size}\}"
      end
    when :OTHER
      arr
    end
  end.
  join
  Regexp.new("\\A" << rstr << "\\z")
end
```

I've made the regex case-insensitive for letters, but that could of course be changed. Also, for some countries, the regex produced may have to be tweaked manually and/or some pre- or post-processing of postal code strings may be called for. For example, some combinations may have the correct format but nonetheless are not valid postal codes. In Australia, for example, the four digits following each region code must fall within specified ranges that vary by region.

Here are some examples.

```
make_regex("12345")
  #=> /\A\d{5}\z/
make_regex("12345-1234")
  #=> /\A\d{5}-\d{4}\z/
Regexp.union(make_regex("12345"), make_regex("12345-1234"))
  #=> /(?-mix:\A\d{5}\z)|(?-mix:\A\d{5}-\d{4}\z)/

make_regex("V8V 3A2", "*")
  #=> /\A[[:alpha:]]\d[[:alpha:]]\s*\d[[:alpha:]]\d\z/ 

make_regex("NSW 1130", "!*")
  # => /\ANSW\s*\d{4}\z/
```

Then, for each country, we take the union of the regexes for each example postal code, saving those results as values in a hash whose keys are country codes.

```
h = example_pcs.each_with_object({}) { |(country, (codes, *examples)), h|
  h[country] = Regexp.union(examples.map { |s| make_regex(s, codes) }.uniq) }
  #=> {:US=>/(?-mix:\A\d{5}\z)|(?-mix:\A\d{5}-\d{4}\z)/,
  #    :CAN=>/\A[[:alpha:]]\d[[:alpha:]]\s*\d[[:alpha:]]\d\z/,
  #    :OZ=>/(?-mix:\ANSW\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\AACT\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\AVIC\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\AQLD\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\ASA\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\AWA\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\ATAS\s*\d{4}\z)|(?-mix:\ANT\s*\d{4}\z)/}
```

```
"12345"      =~ h[:US]
  #=> 0
"12345-1234" =~ h[:US]
  #=> 0
"1234"       =~ h[:US]
  #=> nil
"12345 1234" =~ h[:US]
  #=> nil

"V8V 3A2"    =~ h[:CAN]
  #=> 0
"V8V    3A2" =~ h[:CAN]
  #=> 0
"V8v3a2"     =~ h[:CAN]
  #=> 0
"3A2 V8V"    =~ h[:CAN]
  #=> nil

"NSW 1132"   =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> 0
"NSW   1132" =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> 0
"NSW1132"    =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> 0
"NSW113"     =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> nil
"QLD"        =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> nil
"CAT 1132"   =~ h[:OZ]
   #=> nil
```

The steps performed in `make_regex` for

```
str = "V8V 3A2"
codes = "*+"
```

are as follows.

```
e = str.each_char.chunk do |c|
      case c
      when /\d/          then :DIGIT
      when /[[:alpha:]]/ then :ALPHA
      when /\s/          then :WHITE
      else                    :OTHER
      end
end
    #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f9ff201a330>:each>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[:ALPHA, ["V"]], [:DIGIT, ["8"]], [:ALPHA, ["V"]], [:WHITE, [" "]],
  #    [:DIGIT, ["3"]], [:ALPHA, ["A"]], [:DIGIT, ["2"]]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = e.map do |type, arr|
    case type
    when :ALPHA
      if codes.include?('!')
        arr
      elsif arr.size == 1
        "[[:alpha:]]"
      else "[[:alpha:]]\{#{arr.size}\}"
      end
    when :DIGIT
      (arr.size == 1) ? "\\d" : "\\d\{#{arr.size}\}"
    when :WHITE
      case codes
      when /\*/ then "\\s*"
      when /\+/ then "\\s+"
      else (arr.size == 1) ? "\\s" : "\\s\{#{arr.size}\}"
      end
    when :OTHER
      arr
    end
  end
    #=> ["[[:alpha:]]", "\\d", "[[:alpha:]]", "\\s*", "\\d", "[[:alpha:]]", "\\d"]
rstr = a.join
  #=> "[[:alpha:]]\\d[[:alpha:]]\\s*\\d[[:alpha:]]\\d" 
t = "\\A" << rstr << "\\z"
  #=> "\\A[[:alpha:]]\\d[[:alpha:]]\\s*\\d[[:alpha:]]\\d\\z" 
puts t
  #=> \A[[:alpha:]]\d[[:alpha:]]\s*\d[[:alpha:]]\d\z
Regexp.new(t)
  #=> /\A[[:alpha:]]\d[[:alpha:]]\s*\d[[:alpha:]]\d\z/
```